# Cancelling axios requests when doing 'instant search' type input boxes

Tags: reactjs, axios

I've got:

```
  function testURL(url) {
    return axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/api/test`, { url } )
  }

  onChangeDestination(url, index) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const rules = [...prevState.rules];
      const url_status = "Checking"
      rules[index] = { ...rules[index], url, url_status};
      return { rules };
    });
    if (isURL(url+'')) {
        testURL(url).then(r=> {
          var url_status = r.data.response
          this.setState(prevState => {
            const rules = [...prevState.rules];
            rules[index] = { ...rules[index], url_status};
            return { rules };
          });
        })
      } else {
        this.setState(prevState => {
          const rules = [...prevState.rules];
          var url_status = "No URL"
          rules[index] = { ...rules[index], url_status};
          return {rules};
        });
      }
  };
```

So I have a text input for an URL that on `onChangeDestination` (i.e. a keystroke), does a callback and checks the URL resolves (`url_status`). It's similar to the way google instant search works. The issue I'm having is that sometimes responses to axios can arrive out of order, meaning the final `url_status` is not necessarily from the last keystroke.

I'm trying to work out how to use axios's cancel API, but I'm struggling to figure out how to structure it. What makes sense as a cancel token, and where should I store it?

Comment: Why don't you try some debouncing technique, like [Lodash debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce)

Comment: I didn't know that was an option, it's certainly not a bad idea, although I'd favour doing the cancel + new request if it's easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are asking for this. 
[Axios cancellation](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation)

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
let cancel;
function testURL(url) {
    return axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/api/test`, { url,
      cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
       // An executor function receives a cancel function as a parameter
      cancel = c;
      }
   })
 }


...
// whenever you need to cancel request
// by calling cancel();


onChangeDestination(url, index) {
if(rules[index].url !== url) { // i have added this check 
   cancel();
 // implement  call again() 
}else{
  // usual call 
}
};
...
```

Comment: Would it work if I put the cancel() before the axios request, in order to cancel any previous request?

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel a request using a cancel token.

You can create a cancel token using the CancelToken.source factory as shown below:

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
const source = CancelToken.source();

axios.get('/user/12345', {
  cancelToken: source.token
}).catch(function (thrown) {
  if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
    console.log('Request canceled', thrown.message);
  } else {
    // handle error
  }
});

axios.post('/user/12345', {
  name: 'new name'
}, {
  cancelToken: source.token
})

// cancel the request (the message parameter is optional)
source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');
```

You can also create a cancel token by passing an executor function to the CancelToken constructor:

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
let cancel;

axios.get('/user/12345', {
  cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
    // An executor function receives a cancel function as a parameter
    cancel = c;
  })
});

// cancel the request
cancel();
```

> Note: you can cancel several requests with the same cancel token.

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't helpful to just paste the documentation. If you can help me understand it with respect to my dilemma above, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It should do the trick.
It simply check if the call is being performed (pending state), and if so, navigator cancels it.

```
_source = undefined

testURL = url => {
     if (this._source) this._source.cancel()
     this._source = axios.CancelToken.source()

     return axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/api/test`, 
          { url }, 
          { cancelToken: this._source.token })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

An extra suggestion, apart from the existing ones that show how to cancel a sent-out call (which you should still do). What if you also `debounce` your inputs so there are fewer calls to cancel in the first place?

See http://demo.nimius.net/debounce_throttle/ for what debouncing does.